# Selected Values of a JSON key Fetch to DataFrame in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Structure of JSON looks like below.

```
 |-- destination: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- activity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- destination_class: array (nullable = true)

 |-- Health: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sample: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 
Marks: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- exam_score: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sourceID: string (nullable = true)
 
unique_exam_fields: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- indOrigin: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- compo: string (nullable = true)
```

how come i select only few feilds from each object.
i am trying to bring below feilds to Dataframe.

from destination-- id and activity

from Health-- id and name

from Marks -- exam_score

code:

Code i tried as

val DF = spark.read.json("D:/data.json"),
but the above code bring all feilds

output-- Dataframe looks like

```
destination_id|activity|Health_id|Name|Exam_score
```

Please help

Comment: add complete schema of your json ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dot notation to access the nested structures and then give the columns an [alias](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@as(alias:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```scala
df.select(col("destination.id").as("destination_id"),
      col("destination.activity").as("activity"),
      col("Health.sample.id").as("Health_id"),
      col("Health.sample.name").as("Name"),
      col("Marks.exam_score").as("Exam_score"))
      .show()
```

prints

```
+--------------+--------+---------+----+----------+
|destination_id|activity|Health_id|Name|Exam_score|
+--------------+--------+---------+----+----------+
|             b|       a|        c|   d|         e|
|            b1|      a1|       c1|  d1|        e1|
+--------------+--------+---------+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option: 1** Load complete file & select required columns like below.

Add all required columns inside `Seq` & then use those columns inside `selectExpr`

```
val columns = Seq(
   "destination.id as destination_id",
   "destination.activity as activity",
   "Health.sample.id as health_id",
   "Health.sample.name as name",
   "Marks.exam_score as exam_score"
)
```

```
df.selectExpr(columns:_*)
```

**Option: 2** Create `StructType` with required columns & apply schema before load file data.

```
val schema = // Your required columns in schema
val DF = spark.read.schema(schema).json("D:/data.json")
```